# How can I remove the --shell option in the definition of flycheck-define-checker sh-shellcheck?

Tags: flycheck

Obviously, I could go in and edit the appropriate line in flycheck.el, or copy the function to my init.et and modify it, but then I would be out of sync with any changes in updates to flycheck.

I'd rather write a small Lisp statement that just overrides the :command piece in my init.el. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

A method that might be a bit brutal but might work could be:

```
(setf (flycheck-checker-get 'sh-shellcheck 'command)
      (remove "-shell" (flycheck-checker-get 'sh-shellcheck 'command)))
```

This code needs to run after `flycheck.el` was loaded, of course.

Comment: That’s exactly what I am looking for. Hmm. If there’s a remove, maybe there’s an add too. Thanks. Off to the emacs lisp manual